# Listbox Binding (Caliburn.Micro) - troubleshoot

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am using Caliburn.Micro and try to use MVVM; so my ViewModel and Views are separated; 
I've removed the xaml.cs from the View and run into an issue that my ListBox does not bind to a public ObservableCollection (And I am unable to figure out how)

Consider the following XAML:

```
            <Controls:Tile Title="Track &amp; Trace Reset"
               Controls:ControlsHelper.MouseOverBorderBrush="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.ThemeForeground}"
               Width="155" Height="155"
               HorizontalTitleAlignment="Center"
               x:Name="Button" />
            <ListBox x:Name="LogEntries" ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}"/>
```

and the following class:

```
    public class DebugViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<LogEntryModel> LogEntries = new ObservableCollection<LogEntryModel>(GlobalConfig.Connection.GetLogEntries());

        public void Button()
        {
            GetLogEntries();

        }

        private void GetLogEntries() {
            LogEntries = new ObservableCollection<LogEntryModel>(GlobalConfig.Connection.GetLogEntries());
            //if filter exists, filter the list
            return;
            //Format based on Severity

        }

    }
```

The "Button"-binding works as intended; the ListBox however doesn't display anything (I at least expected some raw-text from the Model that it should display).
The LogEntries gets filled (8 entries) - that also functions;

How can I troubleshoot the binding issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LogEntries` should be defined as a public *property* for the binding to work:

```
public ObservableCollection<LogEntryModel> LogEntries { get; } 
   = new ObservableCollection<LogEntryModel>(GlobalConfig.Connection.GetLogEntries());
```

Also note that using Caliburn.Micro, by convention, you could bind to a property in a corresponding view model by just setting the `Name` property in the view:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LogEntries" />
```

Comment: Thank you; that indeed gives me more to work with; Now it only complains about not being able to find a ViewModel for LogEntryModel; but that's an easy solution!